# MPI - write to same binary file. Each process takes huge difference in time intervals to complete

Tags: c, mpi, binaryfiles

I am trying to write in the same binary file using MPI. I set the offset for each process in the beginning as per the rank. Then the following code snippet in C runs. All MPI process executes and computes the value and it writes to the exact offset as set.

The problem I am facing is, say, out of 32 Process, one process is executed in 2 hours. Rest of the process keeps running for more than 24 hours, The thing is, it computes the values as expected but it takes so much time. It seems like a deadlock situation, each process waits for some resource. But, I am not sharing/communicating between the processes. I am just using MPI_File_write_at to write at a specific location in the binary file. I need to mention that each process computes huge amount of data so storing it temporarily seemed inappropriate.

```
for(i=1;i<=limit;i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<=limit;j++)
    {
        if(my_rank == step%num_cpus)
        {
            Calc = Calculation();
            buf[0] = (double)Calc;
            MPI_File_write_at(outFile, OUT_ofst, buf, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, &status);
            Calc = 0.0;
            OUT_ofst += num_cpus*MPI_File_write_at(sizeof(double));
            count++;
        }
        step++;
    }
}
```

I am new to MPI and I guess people must have had similar issues while executing in MPI. Can anyone help me out please! I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: In this use case, you would typically get the best performance by writing one file per MPI task. Are you sure the time is spent/wasted in `MPI_File_write_at()` and is not the consequence of an imbalance in `Calculation()` ?

Comment: It might have to do with multiple processes holding the same file handle? I would rather let each process write its individual file and then concatenate all files in the end as post processing step.

Comment: One file per rank will work perfectly fine for 32 ranks, but it will stop scaling at some point.

Comment: @JenCat you should really double check your actual issue - right now it sounds like this is based on conjecture. Instead use a parallel debugger or a tool like [STAT](https://computing.llnl.gov/code/STAT/) - if you must, even printf-debugging.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet - Yes, Calculation doesn't have any issues. I have used printf to check how much time each process takes to execute and its fraction of second for each computation. Only when I write, it gets into this issue.

Comment: @Zulan 32 is a sample process size. I'm working on huge data and on a super computer. So, with certain data I do increase my process size to 512 too. Do not want to create those many files. I just want to know why MPI_File_write_at takes different times for each process when the computation count is same for all.

Comment: @JenCat What is the average data size you write per `MPI_File_write_at()` call ? what filesystem are you writing on ? if Lustre, what are the stripe size and count ?

Comment: @JenCat from a performance point of view, there is a time you need to be pragmatic. one file per MPI task is very likely best for speed. If it does not fit your needs, you might simply add a post processing step (possibly within the same MPI program) that reassemble the many files into a single one (If this is a parallel step, then you should use **collective** MPI-IO subroutines to maximize performances.

Comment: @JenCat This may overlap with the comment from Gilles, but I would suggest using collective MPI-IO from within your code rather than in a post-processing step. All you need to do is replace "MPI_File_write_at" with "MPI_File_write_at_all". This will synchronise the processes at the write stage (I'm assuming here that this won't break your program) but allows MPI to aggregate writes and, most importantly, can allow it to avoid locking the file. For hundreds of processes, I have seen increases in speed of orders of magnitude or more from this simple change (for more complicated IO patterns).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I write 8 bytes at a time. It is Lustre, stripe_count = 1, stripe_size = 1048576.

Comment: @JenCat this is pretty awful from a performance point of view...in such a case (all tasks write to the same file), you typically use a high stripe_count (e.g. number of nodes or number of MPI tasks) and hope MPI tasks will write to different stripes to maximize parallelization. But with 8 bytes at a time, I do not see such opportunity. As previously mentioned, one option is one file per MPI task, an other is collective IO (but your tasks would be implicitly synchronized, and that might not be a good fit).

Comment: @JenCat given the very small data written at a time, you might also consider having all MPI tasks send their data to task 0, and have only task 0 write to the output file.

Comment: @DavidHenty I tried MPI_File_write_at_all, like Gilles Gouaillardet mentioned, it doesn't seem to be a good fit. It takes lot more time.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I'm trying two things now: 1) Writing more bytes at a time. 2) As many suggested, writing separate file for each process.

Comment: Can someone direct me to create separate files for each process. I was looking through MPI_Comm_split. Is it a good way to go about it? Thanks!

Comment: All you need is to use a unique file per MPI task. You can use the rank as a suffix for these files.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I used fwrite to write to each file. and, wrote a big chuck of data in each write. Now, my files are generated in 15 minutes! Thanks! So, I learnt MPI_File_write_at, though writes at specific location and just 8 bytes at a time, is a blocking call. That means whoever is writing gets exclusive access to the file until it completes. I'm still not convinced why there is a huge time difference between the processes.

Comment: @JenCat you can see that as MPI tasks competing for a unique lock. Some will get it first, and some will get it last and spend some time waiting (possibly spinning and hence burning CPU usage)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Right, burning CPU usage!